# postgres inverse of json_each

Tags: json, postgresql

I don't have json text in a field. I have a row with columns `"text","format","keyname","..."` and I want to export it to json in the format `'{"value of keyname column": {"text":"value of text","format":"value of format",... }}'`. Is that possible in postgresql?

I have been looking at a postgis2geojson example and learned about the row_to_json function already.
http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/archives/267-Creating-GeoJSON-Feature-Collections-with-JSON-and-PostGIS-functions.html

Furthermore I have been looking at the postgres json documentation: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-json.html

Unfortunately I found no function that covers my need explicitly but `json_each` does what I want just in the opposite direction. Generally, I think the json functions in postgres are designed on the assumption that only the column names can be used as keys. Am I right? Is there a SQL hack I could use to come around this? Thanks for any help.

**EDIT:**

```
select '"'||keyname||'":"'||row_to_json((select r from(Select text, format,
    (select username from my.users where users.id = table.uid) as username,
    machinename ) as r ))||'"'
    from my.table where id = 1;
```

Comment: I think you asking PostgreSQL to do the presentation layer for you, which PostgresSQL and other SQL servers, don't go into - unless you do it yourself using a stored procedure.

Comment: What's wrong with `row_to_json()`?

Comment: Isn't PostgresSQL going into the presentation layer already by providing json conversion? I mean there is a function that does what I want but in the opposite direction. 
Concerning row_to_json(): I have a column "keyname" and I want the VALUES of that column to appear as a json-key. Didn't manage to do that with row_to_json(). Do you?

Answer (score 6):

Since version 9.4 postgres has `json_object_agg` function, which is the inverse of `json_each`. You can read the documentation [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-aggregate.html).

If the data look like this:

```
> select * from example;
 text | format | keyname 
------+--------+---------
 foo  | bar    | a
 dead | beef   | b
(2 rows)
```

Then you can aggregate all of that into an object with keys `a` and `b` with the following query:

```
> select json_object_agg(keyname, json_build_object('text', text, 'format', format)) from example;
                                     json_object_agg                                      
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 { "a" : {"text" : "foo", "format" : "bar"}, "b" : {"text" : "dead", "format" : "beef"} }
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 0):

To keep the API clean I would actually do it a little differently.  You currently have this:

```
select '"'||keyname||'":"'||row_to_json((select r from(Select text, format,
    (select username from my.users where users.id = table.uid) as username,
    machinename ) as r ))||'"'
    from my.table where id = 1;
```

You would have this:

```
WITH full_r AS (select keyname, text, format, username, machinename 
                  FROM my.table JOIN my.users ON users.id = table.uid
                  WHERE id = 1),
     small_r AS (select text, format, username, machinename FROM full_r)
SELECT f.keyname, row_to_json(s)
  FROM small_r s CROSS JOIN full_r f;
```

This assumes only one row returned.  You would want an inner join instead of a cross join if you are working with multiple rows.