# PostgreSQL table to json

Tags: json, postgresql

I have a table

```
 key | value
-----+-------
 a   | "foo"
 b   | "bar"
```

How can I get the result

```
{"a": "foo", "b": "bar"}
```

It doesn't work with

```
select array_to_json(array_agg(t)) from table t; -- I get  [{"key": "a", "value": "foo"}, {"key": "b", "value": "bar"}]
```

Can you help me?

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/90482/export-postgres-table-as-json

Comment: @fuubah Not the same question. In that question the table data was to be output with the column names. Here the column names don't matter, but the data in the table.

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20069143/postgres-inverse-of-json-each

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**PostgreSQL ≥ 9.4 :**

```
SELECT json_object(array_agg(key), array_agg(value))
FROM  t;     

┌────────────────────────────┐
│        json_object         │
├────────────────────────────┤
│ {"a" : "foo", "b" : "bar"} │
└────────────────────────────┘
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using PostgreSQL 9.4 you can use the following code to take key from one column and value from another and create a single JSON object:

```
 select json_object(array_agg(key), array_agg(value)) from table;
```

For earlier versions I don't know of a simple method at this time.

Answer (score 1):

For PostgreSQL 9.4+, there is an [aggregate function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html) specially for this:

```
SELECT json_object_agg(key, value)
FROM   t
```

This avoids the cost of creating 2 PostgreSQL arrays.

For older PostgreSQL versions, you need to concatenate your result yourself:

```
SELECT concat('{', string_agg(to_json(key) || ':' || to_json(value), ','), '}')::json
FROM   t
```

More details:

- [How do I modify fields inside the new PostgreSQL JSON datatype?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18209625/how-do-i-modify-fields-inside-the-new-postgresql-json-datatype/23500670#23500670)